# How to use SaSS for an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sass, gulp

### Problem and question

I've always had problems with CSS code, so now I always use SaSS code. But my question is: how can I use SaSS for an ASP.NET MVC application?

[image]

### I've tried

I've tried tried to use a Gulp task for this. I've used these commands

```shell
npm init
npm install --save gulp
npm install --save gulp-sass
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "markeonline",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Hein Pauwelyn",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the `gulpfile.js`

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass");

// other content removed

gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(project.webroot + './MarkeOnline.Website/Content/css'));
});
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: Solution explorer at Visual Studio]

This code gives me the following error if I use the command below:

```shell
gulp sass
```

> **ReferenceError:** project is not defined
>
> ```
> [17:50:58] ReferenceError: project is not defined
>     at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\gulpfile.js:9:23)
>     at module.exports (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
>     at C:\Users\hein_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>     at Module.runMain (module.js:592:11)
>     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>
> events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> Error: node_modules\node-sass\test\fixtures\depth-first\_vars.scss
> Error: Undefined variable: "$import-counter".
>         on line 1 of node_modules/node-sass/test/fixtures/depth-first/_vars.scss
> >> $import_counter: $import_counter + 1;
>    -----------------^
>
>     at options.error (D:\Documenten\Howest\Semester 4\05 - Project\MarkeOnlinebis\Project Execution\MarkeOnline\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
> ```

Comment: GIF is perfectly accurate. Have you ran through this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa

Comment: Side note: The project shown in the screenshot is from NET Framework 4.x

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) plugin instead this is what I use to compile SCSS in MVC.

> A Visual Studio extension that compiles LESS, Sass, JSX, ES6 and CoffeeScript files.

Comment: For VS2022, use this instead: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score 25):

You can use another way easier I think.

### Step 1

Go with this steps
in your NuGet Manager.

1. Add `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
2. Add `BundleTransformer.SassAndScss`
3. Add `LibSassHost.Native.win-x64` if you use system 64 bit.
4. `LibSassHost.Native.win-x86`

### Step2

In `BundleConfig.cs` add this code in `RegisterBundles` methode.

```
var nullBulider = new NullBuilder();
var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

BundleResolver.Current = new CustomBundleResolver();
var commonStyleBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Bundle/sass");

commonStyleBundle.Include("~/css/main.scss");
commonStyleBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(commonStyleBundle);
```

### Step 3

Add CSS folder in your project and add `main.scss` file sheet inside.

### Step 4

In your view, you need to use `System.Web.Optimization`.

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
```

And link your style sheet

```
@Styles.Render("~/Bundle/sass").
```

### Step 5

In `Global.asax` we need to add this line in `Application_Start()`.

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Or maybe you will find it already in your class if you use MVC templet.

And that is it your `main.scss` its work.

Comment: This works, but I'm concerned about how it puts a load of dlls in the \bin to achieve it.

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can add Sass to your Mvc app:

- Download WebCompiler:
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler&ssr=false#qna
- Double click on the Vsix file to install it.
- Right click on solution, Manage Nuget Packages
- Download bootstrap.sass package (version 4 or above)
- Right click on the bootstrap.scss file under Content folder you need and select Web Compiler - Compile File
- The bootstrap.css file will be generated.
- You can select any scss file to compile.
- You can see the configuration (list of files to be compiled) in the compilerconfig.json file in the root folder.
- Add the css file to the bundle.

  ```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap/main.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
  ```

If you need to customize bootstrap, add a main.scss file in the same folder as bootstrap.scss. Then compile it using Web Compiler.

main.scss:

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "_functions.scss";
@import "_variables.scss";

/* make changes to the !default Bootstrap variables */
$body-color: green;

/* finally, import Bootstrap to set the changes! */
@import "bootstrap.scss";
```

This example includes all the files, but make sure you only add the files you need to make the css smaller.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this solution for net5.0, net6.0, netcoreapp3.1, netstandard2.0

This example shows how to compile scss files from different sources into one single front-end css file.

### What you'll use

- AspNetCore.SassCompiler: `1.53.3`

  - NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.SassCompiler/1.59.3
  - GitHub repo: https://github.com/koenvzeijl/AspNetCore.SassCompiler (to latest version)
- Bootstrap: `5.2.3`

  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/contents/
- Bootswatch: `5.2.2`, Darkly Theme.

  - https://bootswatch.com/ (to latest version)

### INSTRUCTIONS

When creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC project, this is what you'll see in the frontend.

[image]

This is Bootstrap's `5.1.0` default theme, located at `~\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css`. We'll change this default theme using "Sass Compiler Library for .NET Core 3.1/5.x./6.x without node."

#### A. Download Bootstrap (example uses version `5.2.3`)

- Download missing Bootstrap files using libman.json

  1. Right-click on your project.
  2. `Add`, then `Client-Side Library...`, then in `Library:` search for the Bootstrap version you want, then `Install`.

     [image]
- Default installation should:

  - Install all Bootstrap files under `wwwroot` folder, at `lib` folder.
  - We are interested in the content from `scss` folder.

    [image]

#### B. Install `AspNetCore.SassCompiler`

- Using Nuget Package Manager tab:

  1. Right-click on project and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
  2. Browse for the desired package and install it.
- Using Nuget Package Manager or .NET CLI:

  ```
  # Package Manager
  PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.SassCompiler

  # .NET CLI
  dotnet add package AspNetCore.SassCompiler
  ```

#### C. Download Bootswatch files

https://bootswatch.com/

- From their site, pick a theme (we'll pick Darkly):

  [image]
- Download Darkly's Scss files into your project, at top level, inside a newly created folder named `Styles`:

  [image]

  Download both Scss files here:

  [image]

*Note*: Be aware that Bootswacth and Bootstrap must match same versions. I case they don't, go to [Bootswatch's repository](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/) and navigate their branches and commits for getting what you need.

#### D. Compile *ALL* Scss files using `AspNetCore.SassCompiler`

You will add and modify the following files:

- `~/Styles/site.scss`
- `~/Styles/_custom.scss`
- `~/appsettings.json`

```scss
/* ~/Styles/site.scss */

// Bootswatch variables
@import "../Styles/_variables.scss";

// BOOTSTRAP
@import "../wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

// Bootswatch
@import "../Styles/_bootswatch.scss";

// Project custom styling code goes here
@import "../Styles/_custom.scss";
```

The previous file will compile in runtime.

This is the configuration you'll need for `AspNetCore.SassCompiler`

```json
/* ~/appsettings.json */
{
  // ...
  "SassCompiler": {
    "SourceFolder": "Styles",
    "TargetFolder": "wwwroot\\css",
    "Arguments": "--style=compressed",
    "GenerateScopedCss": true,
    "ScopedCssFolders": [ "Views", "Pages", "Shared", "Components" ],
    "IncludePaths": [],

    // You can override specific options based on the build configuration
    "Configurations": {
      "Debug": { // These options apply only to Debug builds
        "Arguments": "--style=expanded"
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

#### Result

- From all of these files:

  - `_variables.scss` +
  - `../wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` +
  - `_bootswatch.scss` +
  - `_custom.scss` →
  - `site.scss` =
- You will get:

  - `~\wwwroot\css\site.css`
- Changing default variables is made as mentioned in the code snippet.
- Adding your own code is made the same way.

  [image]

Will result in:

[image]

(This is from a different project.)

- You'll finally get something like:

  [image]

#### Also

You can add a watcher for runtime:

```cs
// startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
  
#if DEBUG
  services.AddSassCompiler();
#endif

}
```

Or:

```cs
// Program.cs
#if DEBUG
builder.Services.AddSassCompiler();
#endif
```