# Compile Sass Files in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, sass, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to add Sass files to my .NET Core application in Visual Studio 2017. However, I cannot find any way to compile .scss files once I've made them. I sifted through NPM and Bower, but neither offer support for Sass.

The Microsoft documentation for adding Sass (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa) is outdated, and assumes that the project has a package.json file. Any guidance on enabling Sass compiling for my project would be much appreciated.

Comment: I added this probably more generic solution in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75858891/7389293

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way to add .scss to your ASP.NET Core apps is by going to the Nuget Package Manager and installing [LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Core) and [LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Sass](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Sass).

After that, you can just put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.scss" />
```

in the head of the _Layout.cshtml file and the LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Sass package will compile all of your sass files automatically.

Comment: It needs a bit more setup than this. Please check WebOptimizer documentation on https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer and https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer.Sass

Answer (score 5):

Use this extension for Visual Studio https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

This extension not only lets you manually compile SASS/SCSS files to CSS, but it also adds a `compilerconfig.json` which can recompile your CSS every single time you click save.

Additionally, **this extension can compile on project build via a nuget package it can install into your project.** Which also enables CI/CD support.

This is by far the easiest way to add SCSS/SASS compilation to an ASP.NET Core Project when working inside of Visual Studio.

Comment: This extension does not support VS2022 at this moment.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64

Comment: The author of this extension now recommends his newer extension, LigerShark (see answer by smulholland2). https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/566#issuecomment-898610033

Answer (score 4):

Try the article [How to use Sass in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC](https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/how-to-use-sass-in-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc)

If I understood correctly, you can create a blank project.json with node package manager. And you can also configure auto build event with grunt.

Or better yet, follow this tutorial and manually add the file project.json to the project:
<s>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa</s>
(retired doc page, now [redirects to fontawesome](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13221))

Seems that you have missed this part (that file should be created manually):
[image: a screenshot of adding file package.json to the project]

Comment: The link to the microsoft docs now redirects to font awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want SCSS compilation and bundling in one simple tool, try [NBundle](https://github.com/philrawlings/NBundle). (Apologies for the shameless self-plug!)

You specify which files to monitor (wildcards allowed) and the tool can be used to generate compiled and bundled files in a one-shot or "watcher" mode where output files are generated when the source files are saved.

Answer (score 2):

How to accomplish this might depend on your workflow. I'd like it to be part of the build process as seamlessly as possible. So my prefered solution is using a dotnet tool called `excubo.webcompiler`(no I'm not affiliated in any way with the author). If you install it as a project tool

```
dotnet tool install Excubo.WebCompiler
```

you can add a simple target to your project file.

```
<Target Name="CompileStaticAssets" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet webcompiler -r wwwroot" StandardOutputImportance="high" />
</Target>
```

That will use the default settings which will often be sufficient. If not you can [tweak the process](https://github.com/excubo-ag/WebCompiler#configuration) using a configuration file

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a package.json think you getting confused with project.json which was the old project system for .net core projects prior to switching back to .csproj

Comment: What  is  anyone is using it for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use live SASS compiler for compiling SCSS to CSS when the build occurs.
You have to add few line in the .csproj file and prior to that install live sass compiler from npm.
Here is my blog post: [How to Use SCSS with ASP.NET Core 5.X or 3.X](https://pritishcodeblogs.blogspot.com/2021/09/use-scss-with-aspnet-core-5x-or-3x.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30389801)