# Web compiler doesn`t see file outside wwwroot

Tags: visual-studio, sass, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with "Web Compiler" extension for Visual Studio 2019. In .scss file i have reference to bootstrap.scss from node_modules (outside wwwroot). In Rider, where i used to work, i have file watcher that run npm task that compile it live. But in VS2019 it`s Web Compiler doesn`t see files outside root, i have no problem while compiling using the same task. What is the best way to work around this problem? I have three possibilites on my mind

1. Create symlink to bootstrap.scss in wwwroot (but doesn`t work on windows 10, or i just can`t make it work)
2. Copy bootstrap.scss from node_modules to wwwroot (i think its the simplest and the worst option)
3. Use asp.net core static files middleware to add bootstrap module, probably will work

what`s the best way to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Szymon Jędrych, I think you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401075/11398810).

Comment: ill check it out, thanks